# Polymer: How can I load dynamic values into a paper-item within a paper-menu?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I would like to get from javascript code load a list of objects I get from firebase, to the "items" property of a paper-item within a paper-menu. Here's my code:

HTML:

```html
<paper-menu class="menuList" id="disciList" attrForSelected="value" selectedItems="{{selectionDisci}}" multi>
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{disciplines}}">
     <paper-item value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</paper-item>
  </template>
</paper-menu>
```

Javascript:

```js
var disciplines = [];
      var i = 0;
      
      var disciRef = db.ref(exercises.node + exercises.discinames);
      disciRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          disciplines["name" + i] = childSnapshot.key;
          i++;
        });
      });
```

I get the list correctly, but I can not figure out how to load {{items.name}} plus the value of "i" (0-1-2-3 ...) in the paper-item. If there is another way to load the dynamic list, I am open to learning.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a property to bind to the array. Then set the list to that array property.

```
Polymer({
  is: 'custom-element',
  properties: {
    disciplines:
      type: Array,
      value: []
  }

  loadItem: function(){
    //finish loading items to var disciplines then
    this.set('disciplines', disciplines);    
  }
})
```

you can use `index` inside a `dom-repeat` to print the value of 'i'

```
<paper-item value="{{item.name}}">{{index}} {{item.name}}</paper-item>
```

also read the doc for dom-repeat [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat).